# Type Conversion from C to Java

Tags: java, android, c, type-conversion, android-ndk

I did my best to Google this but couldn't find a clean answer in a table-like form that shows type conversions.

The reason I would like to convert these types, is because I am using the Android NDK to call functions from native code. The problem is that the native code calls different types that do not exist in Java.

I actually have no experience in C, and have found these few types from looking at code quickly. Please feel free to edit this post to add different types to be converted.

```
From C to Java

long ->

short ->

char ->

unsigned long ->

unsigned short ->

unsigned char ->

byte ->

Int8 ->

Int16 ->

Int32 ->

UInt8 ->

UInt16 ->

UInt32 ->
```

Also, if any of these cannot convert into a Java type, please explain why.

Comment: Android Dalvik VM is a 32 bits only VM, so the conversion should be trivial. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/11527544/841108

Comment: The signed types with specified widths should map to `byte`, `short`, and `int` as per [this Java Tutorial page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). As for the others, a way to find out would be to print out what `sizeof(long)` et al. tell you when ran on your target device. (The width of C data types is to some extent compiler- and architecture-specific.)

Comment: But `<stdint.h>` gives integral types of known width for C99.

Comment: Properly you should use the j- types (jint, etc) in your interface - level jni code.  And it's up to C to adapt to the needs of java, not the other way around.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Which should probably be used in all C code anyway for portability.

Comment: @ChrisStratton could you elaborate on what you mean? Maybe post another answer? I have no idea what j-types are. My main problem is that I have been given a C library to use in my Java code to build this Android program. At the employers request, I am not supposed to change the C code they have given me. I am allowed to create wrapper functions but not change any of the functions they already have written.

Comment: @JuiCe you will need to read some of the ndk docs and try some of the examples, then think about writing wrappers along those lines.  But if the existing code makes assumptions about process lifetime and static state in conflict with the Android activity lifecycle and emphasis on activities rather than procceses, there may be no proper solution within your constraints of not changing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are the equivalences, bearing in mind that the size of a primitive data type in Java is always the same, whereas the size of a data type in C is to some extent compiler-and architecture-specific, as pointed by @millimoose in the comments.

Also, be aware that the `char` data type is [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types) as "smallest addressable unit of the machine that can contain basic character set. It is an integer type. Actual type can be either signed or unsigned depending on implementation", whereas in Java is a single 16-bit Unicode character.

```
long -> long
short -> short
char -> char
unsigned long -> N/A
unsigned short -> N/A
unsigned char -> N/A
byte -> byte
Int8 -> byte
Int16 -> short
Int32 -> int
UInt8 -> N/A
UInt16 -> N/A
UInt32 -> N/A
```

In Java there are no unsigned primitive data types. The `byte` type uses 8 bits, `int` 32 bits, `short` 16 bits and `long` 64 bits.

Here's a [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) to the relevant section in the Java tutorial, and a more detailed explanation in [section §4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2) of the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html).

Comment: Why is it that several of these are N/A?

Comment: @JuiCe Java doesn't support unsigned types. Depending on what you need to do, you need to convert to a bigger signed type (for computation), or to the signed type (when it's important to keep the same bit pattern.)

Comment: @JuiCe That would mean that Java does not have an equivalent type.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Wouldn't `Int8` map to `byte`?

Comment: @EricFinn Haha yes I knew that's what it meant, I was looking for more of an in depth explanation. Can anyone delve a little deeper into the meaning of an unsigned type and why Java does not support them?

Comment: @JuiCe Ah. Unsigned types are nonnegative (they don't have a sign bit). I'm not sure why Java doesn't support them, though.

Comment: @EricFinn Gosling hates them is why: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c_family_interview.htm

Comment: @ChrisStratton please expand on your comment, why?

Comment: Java's `chars` are UCS-2 code points. (Or maybe UTF-16 sequences.) So it's more equivalent to C's `wchar`. Maybe. I can never remember how exactly you're supposed to work with Unicode in plain C.

Comment: char do not map to char. Java char's are 2 bytes (UNICODE), while C char's are 1 byte (ASCII only).

Comment: @jsn I updated my answer with an additional clarification on this point

Comment: Given that this is tagged android, you really need to get rid of the char-char mapping as it's completely untrue on this platform where a char is an 8-bit type.

Comment: Anyone clarify on what Chris Stratton just said?

Answer (score -1):

you need to import class

Class UInt32

java.lang.Object

And then you can simple use Uint32 and Uint16